# Can i save returned live stream object in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, video-streaming

```
share.addEventListener("click", event => {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getDisplayMedia()

        .then(returnedStream => {
         
          stream = returnedStream;
          video.srcObject = stream;
});
```

I want to save stream in localstorage

Answer (score 1):

Not at all recommended. LocalStorage has different file size limits for each browser, all of which are only a few megabytes; barely enough to hold a single image.

[What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)